# Insert data from local to [LINKEDSERVER]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to insert data from my own local table to a table in my built linkedserver. I'm having some trouble. Please see.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [LinkedServerName].[database].[Schema].[table]
```

The data can be queried, and the linkserver connection is no problem

```
INSERT INTO [LinkedServerName].[database].[Schema].[table]  
(row1, row2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

> error message: Cursor support is not an implemented feature for SQL
> Server Parallel DataWarehousing TDS endpoint.

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO [database].[Schema].[table] (row1, row2) VALUES (value1, value2)') AT [LinkedServerName]
```

This insert works, it succeeds, but I have a lot of data, inserting one by one with a cursor will affect the speed.

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO [database].[Schema].[table] (row1, row2) SELECT r1,r2 form [mylocalserver].[database].[Schema].[table]') AT [LinkedServerName]
```

> [mylocalserver].[database].[Schema].[table] doesn't exist
> LinkedServer.

So how can I reference my LOCAL table inside the "EXEC() AT" syntax?

I also tried insert openquery

```
insert into openquery([LinkedServerName],'Select row1, row2 from [database].[Schema].[table]' )
select r1, r2 from [mylocalserver].[database].[Schema].[table]
```

> error message: Cursor support is not an implemented feature for SQL
> Server Parallel DataWarehousing TDS endpoint.

I want to know how to solve it, thank you all.

Comment: I think you can try to use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement to insert data from your local table to the linked server table in a single query.

Comment: I know you meaning . i tried , but it has a problem.
error message: **Cursor support is not an implemented feature for SQL Server Parallel DataWarehousing TDS endpoint.**

Comment: Ok. How about `#tempTable`? Did you try it?

Comment: I just tested the same error

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (
    row1 datatype,
    row2 datatype
)

INSERT INTO #temp_table
(row1, row2)
SELECT r1, r2
FROM [mylocalserver].[database].[Schema].[table]

INSERT INTO [LinkedServerName].[database].[Schema].[table]
(row1, row2)
SELECT row1, row2
FROM #temp_table

DROP TABLE #temp_table
```

Comment: I don't know how to insert pictures, but it doesn't work.
**Cursor support is not an implemented feature for SQL Server Parallel DataWarehousing TDS endpoint.**

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/remotely-run-ddl-and-dml-in-synapse-from-a-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/2157122

This link is the result given by the Microsoft community, but it cannot meet my needs